# How to use .live() jQuery and .hover() combined?

Tags: jquery

my dilemma is about .live() and .hover(). What I wanted is that, every time I click my 'Buy Now' button, it will then update my sidebar(updating it will not load the page) which contains the number of how many have purchased that item, and when I hover a cart image on the sidebar, it will show me the full purchase details(which I hid, because I wanted it only to show when being hovered). But right after I clicked the 'Buy Button', saw the update of purchases, I tried to hover on the sidebar but sadly it did not display the full details, it was then the hover worked normally after I refreshed the page. A friend told me to use .live() but found it complicated for me because I'm still a newbie. Can anyone please guide me? :(

code:

```
$('#shoppingCart').hover(
    function(){
        //div
        $('#div_widget').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.cartDivLight').addClass('cartDivDark');

    },
    function(){
        //div
        $('#div_widget').addClass('hidden');
        $('.cartDivLight').removeClass('cartDivDark');
    }
);
```

, this is what my script looks like, I wanted to integrate .live(), but it won't work.:(

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `live()` and `hover()` combined. In fact, as of jQuery1.7, you should instead use the jQuery method `on()` instead of `live()` which is being deprecated (i.e., removed from future jQuery releases). http://api.jquery.com/on/

The basic advantage of the  `live()`, `delegate()`, `on()` methods is that you can use them to do an event: hover, click, etc., on an element that doesn't exist yet until you add that element later via AJAX, JavaScript's `createElement` method, etc.

Here's how to use `on()`:

```
$('#container').on('hover', '#clickableElement', function({ console.log('do something'); });
```

`#container` is the element within which `#clickableElement` resides or will ultimately reside. You could also use `document.body` instead, but `#container` narrows the focus so jQuery doesn't have to search as much to find the `#container` selector.

here's a jsfiddle to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/WrXVu/44/

the mouseover behavior is kind of screwed up but you'll get the idea,

Comment: thanks for that, but how about if I won't use click, instead I'll use hover but, the element I want to hover is the container itself, is that even possible?

Comment: "is the container itself" -- then bind `on` to the element your element is nested to

Comment: hi bunsiChi, you can swap: 'click', 'hover', 'focus', or other 'events' in the 1st parameter in the code I show above. Yes, you can hover over the container or any element. In this case the selector could just be 'document.body' just to be safe.

Comment: hi bunsiChi, i'm making testable code based on your question above right now on jsfiddle.net, give me a few minutes and i'll get back with you...

Comment: hi BunsiChi, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/WrXVu/44/ or http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/WrXVu/46/, mouseenter/mouseleave is not my strong suit, but hopefully the demo demonstrates enough principles

Comment: @bunsiChi can you give an indication of why you unaccepted my answer? I'd be happy to help explain if my answer still doesn't make sense in some way.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your sidebar is structured something like this :

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="shoppingCart">
        <div class="static">
            //icon & title
        </div>
        <div class="purchase_details">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shoppingCart">
        <div class="static">
            //icon & title
        </div>
        <div class="purchase_details">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the corresponding javascript will be :

```
$('#sidebar').on('mouseenter', '.shoppingCart', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find('.static').addClass('cartDivDark');
        $this.find('.purchase_details').show();
    }).on('mouseleave', '.shoppingCart', function() {
        $this.find('.static').removeClass('cartDivDark');
        $this.find('.purchase_details').hide();
    }
);
```

This will not be 100% correct because I don't have sight of your HTML, but it should demonstrate the necessary principles.

Notes:

- `.on()` supersedes `.live()`, `.delegate()` and `.bind()` from jQuery 1.7.1.
- We use `.on()` to delegate event handling to the sidebar, on behalf of current and future carts.
- You can't delegate hover with `.on('hover' ...)`, but you can delegate hover's two component events, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.
- Everything inside the sidebar is identified by class, not id. This allows us to write generalised mouseenter and mouseleave handlers that operate on elements within the hovered element.

Comment: hello Beetroot, I don't know what exactly happened but when I used your style, an error '$().on is not a function' occurs.

Comment: You are most likely using a version of jQuery that doesn't support `.on()`. Latest is 1.7.2